# find files in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, filezilla

I update a company website which recently began hosting with AWS. I am used to accessing the files via ftp using Filezilla. I have been thru several tutorials and finally was able to get Filezilla connected with an instance. But the files I used to see are not there. 
Please can anyone help me? I'm not an expert I just can't wrap my head around AWS despite reading their tutorials and also watching other tutorials. I just want to see the files, be able to download or upload them as I wish.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the files I used to see are not there"? Used to see _where_? What software are you running and what files are you wanting to transfer? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details. Please note, however, that StackOverflow is for programming-related questions. For Systems  Administration activities, you should ask at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: There is not enough information here for a concise answer to be given. We can give high-level suggestions, but no true answers without knowing more about what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not as much of an AWS issue as it is an issue with the way that you expect the specific data on your instance to work.

That said, it's possible that you created the instance with an instance store-backed volume instead of an EBS-backed volume. The former of the two is ephemeral, which means that the data is not kept when you terminate or reboot the machine. The EBS volumes will keep the data, because there is a separate resource allocated in your account for the storage.

In order for someone to be able to help you here, can you give details on which AWS services you are using, which instance AMI you are using, and what you've done to manually keep it running.

Furthermore, I am not sure that stackoverflow is the right place for this. It may get more attention on ServerFault.

Comment: AWS is very ephemeral to me! Thanks for your help. I think we need to hire someone to help us. I'm getting no where fast.  Thanks also for the tip about SeverFault

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be talking about connecting to Amazon EC2 instances (virtual machines).

Once an instance is booted (with Linux or Windows), it is a perfectly normal computer running a standard copy of the operating system. There is nothing specific to AWS when it comes to running software on the instance itself.

Therefore, your question is probably more related to whatever software you are expecting to be on the instance. You should seek assistance regarding that software rather than AWS.

Comment: OK, I appreciate your help. I'm such a novice that AWS is just too much. We'll need to hire someone just to help us with the hosting!

Comment: No. The hosting is easy and you've already done it. It sounds like you'll need assistance with the actual software you are running, which has nothing to do with where the system is "hosted".

Comment: Yes, you're right John. I just need help in setting up some kind of software that allows me to see the files on the AWS server. I am at a loss as to how that works.